# SQL find matches in same column

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm working on an assignment for class and the question asks to find matches in the same column on the same table. and to list all rows that have this match. Let me just post the question to better explain it:

*List the part number, part description, and item class for each pair of parts that are in the same item class. (For example, one such pair would be part AT94 and part FD21, because the item class for both   parts is HW.)*

I'm not sure which function to use to do this. Does the teacher just want us to group the results by class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to give you part of the answer:

You need pairs. So you'll be essentially GROUPing items HAVING a count of 2.

Good luck!

---

Addendum:

Remember to use aggregating functions for all items after SELECT that are not in GROUP BY. Depending on the database engine you are using, there are concatenation functions which could be useful.

Comment: Not necessary. Pairs of items are simply items where item 1 and item 2 have the same value in a column.

Comment: Of course there are always more than one way to get what you want. The OP could JOIN the table with itself and get something out of that. Not ideal.

Comment: Agreed, but the self-join will be necessary if he wants the values from both items in a single result record.

Comment: @drdwilcox Not necessarily. Contatenation aggregate functions would allow him to group the items by record.

Comment: -1 This isn't right. It's not even wrong. It's simply misleading mumbo-jumbo.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck It's called not giving out the answer straight up to a learning student.

Comment: @MPelletier It would be if it pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the teacher, grad assistant, or smartest kid in the class is better able to interpret the teacher's intent. You don't, however, need to GROUP to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT part_nr, part_desc, item_class
FROM parts
ORDER BY item_class

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for Group By.  Since this is homework, I'm not going to provide a specific example, but the syntax is generally

```
SELECT [COLUMNS]
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE [PREDICATE] --Okay, all that's normal in SQL
GROUP BY [COLUMN] --This column should be a named column in your SELECT statement.
```

Update:  As MPelletier says, you also want "HAVING"

Happy hunting.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT F.ITEM_NUM, S.ITEM_NUM, F.DESCRIPTION, S.DESCRIPTION, F.CATEGORY, S.CATEGORY
FROM ITEM F, ITEM S
WHERE F.CATEGORY = S.CATEGORY
AND F.ITEM_NUM < S.ITEM_NUM
ORDER BY F.ITEM_NUM, S.ITEM_NUM;`
```

Answer (score -2):

You should join the table with itself.

Something like this may put you on the right track:

```
select <list of fields> 
from parts p1
inner join parts p2 on p1.item_class = p2.item_class
where p1.part_number < p2.part_number
```

There are a couple of caveats with the result from this statement.

For example:

You will get duplicates on the form (a,b) and (b,a)

You will get also every item joined with itself (a,a).

**Edit:**

Fixed the caveats (by adding the where clause).

Comment: That's an awkward approach, because the join will create 4 items: item1-item1, item1-item2, item2-item1, and item2-item2. Then you have to filter all that crap.

Comment: I assume the due date of the assignment has passed by now, so I have added the "awkward" filter to get rid of "all that crap". I doubt that any solution using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`is simpler than this.